# How should I reverse engineer this simple javascript animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, graph, decompiling

I came across [this Slate article](http://www.slate.com/articles/sports/fivering_circus/2012/07/olympics_interactive_how_would_the_champs_of_bygone_olympics_fare_against_today_s_best_sprinters_jumpers_throwers_and_swimmers_.html?fb_action_ids=10101816136988733&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%2210101816136988733%22:10151043648722767%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210101816136988733%22%3a%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D) that presents data in a new and interesting way.  How can I reverse engineer the website so I can learn, and potentially imitate the technique on my own.

To keep this constructive for future websites, please describe the general steps and what tools I would need to efficiently break the code down into manageable chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that you need many tools other than a web browser and view source. You probably will want to extract some of it into your own html/javascript files to test to make sure you have all the relevant code - not sure what else you might need. I think it's a lot of trial and error.

In this particular case, viewing the source would give you your answer pretty easily - it's not obfuscated at all. View source and look for

```
<!--**********************PASTE THIS INTO RENDER HTML************* -->
```

Right under that they include the [javascript file](http://img.slate.com/features/2012/athleteRace/race.js) relevant to the races and they have the html structure that their javascript uses.

Comment: I'd add that Chrome has plenty of support for browsing the code,html etc. Stepping, debug writes, watching variables etc. FF+Firebug has similar, IE9 has too. Just press f12 and have a look around

Comment: What about the `general steps`?

Comment: I think the general steps is look at the code, look for the html elements and the javascript code that might hook up to it via class or element ids